# Is Java/1.6.0_24 a Bot and How to force them to refresh their link

Tags: c#, asp.net, robots.txt, bots

We've now got plenty of sites which all use a log4net base error loging framework and we receive error from site from anywhere it append. We've notice that some of them catch error because of "Bot" like google, bing, yahoo, etc. But there's a things we've not sure about how to resolve. I've two questions about it :

1. Is "Java/1.6.0_24" a Bot? Because the user-agent of my question #2 is about this.
2. The "Java/1.6.0_24" still calling subfolder on our site that just do not exists! Like, if we have a page called "Page1.aspx", instead of calling "~/Page1.aspx", he calls it "~/minisite/Page1.aspx". How can I tell him he's wrong? Is there a way to do it?

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's most likely a bot but it could as well be some kind of browser based on Java that sends that user-agent string - you can't trust it 100% but it can give you an estimate idea of what the connecting entity is. Depending on the kind of bot it might as well just ignore your robots.txt so I'd just impement some handling stuff somewhere.
2. Did those folders ever exist? If so, you could use [HTTP's permanent redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx) (code 301) to tell him to no longer look there - however that doesn't guarantee it will do so.

Comment: Thank you Mario. But must say that the subfolder never exists at all. I'll try the HTTP's permanent redirect

Comment: In that case I'd just return HTTP 404 and screw the bot, tool or whatever. It's not in your responsibility to satisfy all requests, especially those that were never valid. Just add some additional filter if those errors cluster up your log files.

Comment: But it means I must create the file? Like, if he calls "~/microsite/Page1.aspx" and it not exists, I create it and return a HTTP 404 or there's another way to do it?

Comment: No, there should be some kind of error handling happen somewhere in your code. If there isn't, the web server should handle it (Web.config). Example code and details can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417.aspx